# Override brabeion templates path in Django

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, django-apps, overriding

I'm using brabeion in my project and I noticed that it comes with a urls.py and a views.py files, the problem is that it doesn't come with the respective templates required for the views to work.

I found this in the brabeion's source:

views.py:

```
return render_to_response("brabeion/badges.html", {
    "badges": sorted(badges_dict.items()),
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Since it doesn't come with any template file, how can I make it to use my own?

I've tried creating a template file named "badges.html" and placing it in my template folder, but it was useless. There has to be a way to use the existing views with my own templates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder named `brabeion` in your templates directory (templates/brabeion) and then place the requested html files.
Don't forget to set you `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable to point to the templates folder in the `settings.py`.